# Why does my App lags when scrolling UICollectionView (Swift)?

Tags: xcode, swift, uicollectionview

Could anyone please help me? I am creating an app, I am using swift and I have trouble with the uicollectionview. I don't know if there is a bug on my code, the problem is the app is already running but when scrolling the uicollectionview the application lags. The cell contains image from our website, the image size is 175x175 pixels and I am using https because of the security feature on xcode7. Anyone please help. Thank you in advanced.

[function where i get data from our website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd5c5.jpg)

[script where i populate the cell with image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPbxp.jpg)

Comment: We can't help if you don't show code.

Comment: sorry, i've edited the post now.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots, paste the relevant sections into your question, using the formatting tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the future, it is better to post the relevant code here rather than post an image of all the code.

You can start off with changing the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` implementation. You are downloading the image in the method (as a synchronous implementation). So unless the image is downloaded by `contentsOfURL:` and rendered, the cell won't display. And the image is being downloaded every time the cell renders.

A better alternative is to download images in a separate thread, keep them for later use (and avoid downloading every time) and update the cell when the image is available. You can use an existing implementation like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) to make things easier for you.

Comment: thank you, i'll be doing that from now on.